# How do you use CSS to place a background image in a Titanium iOS App

Tags: background-image, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I am working on a Titanium app and have a div with a css background image.
Normally it is possible to have the background-image url point to either the absolute or the relative path.
For Example:

```
background-image: url('../images/my_backgriund_pic.png');
```

Tests:
1. When opening the html file in a browser, the image gets displayed as is normally the case.

2. When I deploy the app to the simulator I have to put in the absolute path like so

   background-image: url('file:///Users/cassiel/Desktop/Definition12/Appcelerator/smedrix_test/Resources/images/my_backgriund_pic.png');
3. But I haven't been able to get the image displaying when the app is deployed on the phone
   I always get an error like so:

Error loading /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B269D1DC-DEE4-45D5-B5F3-BAD1333E1C17/smedrix_test.app/images/smedrix/info_text_01_header_1Zeiler.png

Can anyone help me out with this one ?

Thanx
Chris

Answer (score 0):

in titanium there isn't div, you need to use Ti.UI.View
and in the .tss ( not .css ) use this properties

```
   backgroundImage:'url or imagePath'
```

Comment: but when creating a Ti.UI.createWebView() then it is possible to use an html file together with a css styling file.
And I have a problem with using the css background-image property.
It doesn't seem to find the image